# Is it possible to stop Hyper-V renaming the WiFi connection to "Ethernet"?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Hyper-V needs to do something with the network drivers to allow for a host OS to access the external network. This interferes with the actual network device and renames it to "Ethernet". This is less than ideal when using a Laptop that already has an Ethernet connection.

[image: Proper device name]

[image: New name]

Is there any way of stopping Hyper-V/Windows/Task Manager from renaming the device to Ethernet? Not a major issue but annoying none the less, and confusing when the real Ethernet connection is connected too.

Comment: No; That is just how Hyper-V works.  The adapter name is clearly indicated though.

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: Bridging is no good with WiFi anyway.

Comment: @DanielB What do you mean?

Comment: @user9993 The [Client Mode Wireless](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode#bridged_client_mode_issues) page in the OpenWrt Wiki has a good explanation on this.

Comment: So your saying Hyper-V doesn't work with laptops that have WiFi?

Comment: Hyper-V is more than networking. Bridged connections might work, but you’ll likely encounter intermittent connection problems on your host or any of the VMs currently running. For a fully compatible network experience, you’ll have to use a wired network connection.

Answer (score 1):

It's not renaming the adapter, its a different (virtual) adapter that abstracts your physical adapter for use with the virtual switched network Hyper-V uses.

Here's a good visualization of how the virtual network works:

[image]

The orange box is the adapter on your host.

You should be able to use PowerShell 4.0's [Rename-VMNetworkAdapter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848517(v=wps.630).aspx) command to rename the adapter if you'd like.

[More info/picture source](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/the-hyper-v-virtual-switch-explained-part-1/)